# Golang - Comparison operator not defined on interface converted to float64

Tags: go, comparison, switch-statement, type-conversion

As shown in the code below, I'm doing some type switching on an `interface{}` in order to do the correct type switching - I'm trying to convert the `interface{}` to either a `float64` or a `string` and then comparing it to a value, however, when using a comparison operator other than `==` on the `float64`'s, Go complains about it when building.

The errors Go spits out are as follows :-

```
invalid operation: (interface {})(val.(float64)) > subval.Value (operator > not defined on interface)
invalid operation: (interface {})(val.(float64)) >= subval.Value (operator >= not defined on interface)
invalid operation: (interface {})(val.(float64)) < subval.Value (operator < not defined on interface)
invalid operation: (interface {})(val.(float64)) <= subval.Value (operator <= not defined on interface)
```

...and this is my code:-

```
val:= s.FieldByName(subval.Metric).Interface()
switch val(type) {
case float64, float32, int:
    switch subval.Type {
    case "greater_than":
        if val.(float64) > subval.Value {
            runAction(subval.Action, Config)
        }
    case "greater_than_or_equal_to":
        if val.(float64) >= subval.Value {
            runAction(subval.Action, Config)
        }
    case "equal_to":
        if val.(float64) == subval.Value {
            runAction(subval.Action, Config)
        }
    case "less_than":
        if val.(float64) < subval.Value {
            runAction(subval.Action, Config)
        }
    case "less_than_or_equal_to":
        if val.(float64) <= subval.Value {
            runAction(subval.Action, Config)
        }
    }
case string:
    if subval.Type == "equal_to" {
        if val.(string) == subval.Value {
            runAction(subval.Action, Config)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First: Your type assertion `val.(float64)` will panic if `val` is a `float32`. Second: The comparison errors most likely come from `subvalue.Value` not being a `float64` but some `interface{}`. Just show a full example in the playground.

Comment: +1 for the playground example. I will add that the following [example](http://play.golang.org/p/32zgpCizkA) works fine, so the problem is probably the `subval.Value` being an interface.

Comment: subval.Value was indeed an Interface, my bad. If either of you two want to submit an answer then i'll gladly mark is as Accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is probably that `subval.Value` is an `interface{}`, so the comparison operator isn't available. I think that when doing an equality comparison with an interface, go compare the underlying types byte-wise, hence the `==` not giving an error.

Comment: Is there a way to solve this? Can i define operators for interface?

Answer (score 0):

If someone got here like me, then for him I will describe my situation like this. Let it be here

I had a similar problem. It was necessary to compare the two ints that the List container returns as interfaces.

I solved it this way:

1. Initialized the variable
2. Assigned it a value that I return using fmt.Sprint() - this function returns the passed value as a string to your variable.
3. Then I converted the string to the type I needed
4. And so I was able to compare these values

For example:

```
list1.Front().Value > list2.Front().Value // i cant compare it because this 
                                         //  method returns inerfase{}
value1 := fmt.Sprint(list1.Front().Value) // so if you do it this way
value2 := fmt.Sprint(list2.Front().Value) 


// ...CONVERTING TO int's USING func Atoi()
// you can compare these two values
isItTrue := value1 > value2
```